# Can't start applications in eclipse in debug mode on newly installed mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have reinstalled snow leopard (10.6.4) and it's fully updated. Running java -version gives me:
Java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02-279-10M3065)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01-279, mixed mode)

I have installed a fresh version of eclipse (helios, 3.6, build: 20100617-1415).

I create a new java project, add a simple test case:

```
public class TestMyEclipse {  
      @Test  
      public void testIt() {  
       assertTrue(true);  
      }  
}
```

When I run this in normal mode in eclipse it works as expected. But when I run it in debug mode I get the following error:

```
Invalid memory access of location 0x14 rip=0x1007f9d22
```

Comment: Can you compile and run your program outside of eclipse in debug mode?

Comment: Can you try it with this *** [eclipse.ini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659) *** and check if the problem persists?

Comment: I can run a java app from the terminal both in normal mode (java Test) and in debug mode (jdb Test).

Comment: Is there some additional hint in the error log view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that your localhost has been removed from your hosts entry.  I've posted a blog entry detailing how I fixed it.  http://yadg.blogspot.com/2011_01_01_archive.html

Comment: what is the line of code for that? do i need a # in front of 127.0.0.1?

Comment: i made sure 127.0.0.1 ddint have a # in front of it at it started working again. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found another blog which describes the problem and the solution in greater detail. Here is the link if it helps:

http://apachefelix.blogspot.com/2012/05/offtopic-mac-cant-resolve-localhost-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Type /private/etc in the finder.

Look for the hosts file. Edit it and paste:

127.0.0.1      localhost

I used sublime and it'll ask sudo credentials before saving the modified file.